# Find the image of 4,2 around line 2x + 3y - 5

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to do this vectorially but other neat methods are welcome.

So first I'll find the x intercept of my line, that happens at $ x= 5/2$

Now from( 5/2, 0) I'll draw a vector to (4,2) I'll call this $a = (4 - 5/2,2)= (3/2,2)$

I'll draw vector b from the x intercept to the image. I'll just Call that $b$

Now the vector of my line $c = (3,-2)$

Since c is angular bisector of isosceles triangle formed by intercept, vector a and b -

$k*c =|a|b + |b|a$ where k is some constant and a and b are above mentioned vectors of equal magnitude. Annnd now I'm stuck. I can't work out what k is so that i can find b so that i can find the point by vector addition.

I want to do it this way bc it looks way faster than distance formula stuff, and also that vectors apply quite nicely to the straight line problems in my book so I'd be glad if anyone can tell me how to proceed here or perhaps something else entirely.

Comment: Do you mean the *reflection* of $(4,2)$ in the given line?

Comment: @amd yes, that's is what i meant